# primefaces datatable row returns null value after filtering

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, filtering

I have a primefaces datatable which displays a list of cars. One of the columns of the datatable has a command button which when clicked opens a dialog box which displays information about the selected car. Everything works as expected until I default filter the datatable and select the command button of a filtered row. The details of the car is null in this case. How can I get the value (car object) of the selected row after filtering?

```
<h:form id="carView">
<h:panelGrid id="carPanelGroup" style="width:100%" styleClass="tblNowrap100pct">
`<p:dataTable value="#{carBean.carList}" var="car"  id="carTbl" stripedRows="true" rendered="#{not empty carBean.carList}" showGridlines="true" styleClass="tblNowrap100pct" filteredValue="#{carBean.filteredValues}" rowKey="#{car.carId}">

    <p:column headerText="Car Name" sortBy="#{car.carName}" filterBy="#{car.carName}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Car Name" />
            </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.carName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column  headerText="Make"    sortBy="#{car.make}"   filterBy="#{car.make}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Make" />
            </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.make}" />
            </p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Car Download" /> 
</f:facet>
<p:commandButton action="#{carBean.selectCar}" value="Download"                         styleClass="linkButton" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('carDownloadpanel').show();" update="@all">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{carBean.carDto}"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>`
</p:dataTable>
</p:panelGrid>
</h:form>   


            <!-- ******** pop up -->
    <p:outputPanel id = "downloadOutputPanel">
    <p:dialog header="#{carBean.carDto.carName}" widgetVar="carDownloadpanel" width="500" height="400" id="dialogDetails" modal="true">
    
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="#{carBean.carDto.carName}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:form id="carDetailView">
            <p:panel>
                <p:panelGrid id="carDetails" columns="2" styleClass="summaryTable"
                    columnClasses="colLabel, colNormalInputArea" rendered="#{not empty firmBean.firmDto}">
                    <h:outputText value="Car Name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{carBean.carDto.carName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Firm Id:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{carBean.carDto.carId}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="iwaInfo">
            <h:panelGrid id="carReportInput" columns="2" styleClass="summaryTable" columnClasses="colLabel, colNormalInputArea">
            
                <p:commandLink value="Download" id="downloadBtn" 
                    action="#{carBean.downloadCar}" onclick="PF('carDownloadpanel').hide();">
                </p:commandLink> 
            
                <p:commandLink value="Cancel" id="cancelBtn"
                    oncomplete="PF('carDownloadpanel').hide();" update=":carView:carPanelGroup" process="@parent"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog> 
    </p:outputPanel>




Java method :

    public String selectCar(){
        if (this.carDto != null) {
            carId = this.carDto.getCarId();
            instanceId = this.carDto.getInstanceId();
        
        if (carId!=null&&instanceId!=null){
            CarDto dto = new CarDto();
            List<CarDto> sLst = carService.searchCar(Long.parseLong(carId), Long.parseLong(instanceId));
            if (sLst!=null&&sLst.size()>0){
                dto= sLst.get(0);
            }           
            setCarDto(dto);
        }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What's your Primefaces version?

Comment: @WoAiNii I have primefaces 10.0.0

Comment: Where do you display the selected car? Do you mean that the selected is null in `selectCar` method? Can you post all the relevant info/code?

Comment: @WoAiNii Thanks for your response. I've edited the post with all the code. The carDto which is set using the f:setPropertyActionListener of the commandLink is null in the carBean class' selectCar method. The details of the car are shown in a dialog box when the commandlink is clicked. I've added the code for the pop up dialog as well.  Note: carDto is null only after filtering. It works otherwise

Comment: Still missing some info, like what and how the data table is filtered, please post the full relevant part of the code. Trying what you write above, in my test project, the button works fine, even when filtered, so, maybe you've got a nested form or others problem. Hence integrate your question with what's needed to replicate the issue.

Comment: @WoAiNii Apologies. I just edited the above code to include the form and a couple of other columns from the datatable. When I filter the table on the UI using say for example the car name, and I select the download button on one of the filtered rows (which is for example 4 rows out of a datatable size of 100 and I select the download button on one of the 4 rows), then the value of carDto in the carBean is null. I hope i'm clear this time.

Comment: @WoAiNii Additional information : this EAR is deployed on Weblogic 12c if that has any significance.